# How to extract the words behind and above a keywords range in TokenRegex?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using TokenRegex for my words extraction project and meet the following problem.

Eg. Sentence: Someone guesses to go there and have a lunch today

If I want to extract "to go there and have a lunch", how to set the pattern to extract the words from "guesses" to "today"?

I have tried
{

```
            ruleType: "tokens",

            pattern: (  [ !{ word: /guesses/ } ] []{1,}  [ { word:/today/  } ]),

            result: "Weight"
```

}

It just highlights the words: to go there and have a lunch today, not: to go there and have a lunch